# How to track app installs and CPI for a LinkedIn campaign ?

Tags: android, ios, mobile, linkedin-api

I am studying the possibility to promote my app with LinkedIn ads.

I would like to know if it is possible with this network to track accurately my app installs, CPI, etc... Like on other networks like AdMob/AdWords...

I see that there is a SDK https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/android-sdk but I don't manage to understand if it is designed to send calls to LinkedIn in order to track the installs due to my LinkedIn campaign (in order to allow LinkedIn to display the app installs due to the campaign, the CPI, etc...).

Finally, does the LinkedIn's dashboard give these KPIs like the app installs and CPIs ?

If i cannot do that with LinkedIn, is there a workaround in order to run a LinkedIn campaign and follow properly the KPIs ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In general it works like this for install tracking attribution on Android. I do not know about LinkedIn specifically, but it would be weird if they do not do this too:

When someone clicks on the Ad the Customer is sent to a URL that tracks the click on LinkedIns site then the Operating System of the customer is determined and he is sent to the play store with a link that will look likes this `https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.example.application
&referrer=utm_source%3Dgoogle
%26utm_medium%3Dcpc
%26utm_term%3Drunning%252Bshoes
%26utm_content%3Dlogolink
%26utm_campaign%3Dspring_sale`

When the App install you will get an Intent from the System into your app and it will contain the referrer parameter as an Extra and you can track it any way you want. Tracking frameworks like Google Analytics can also take care of this for you.

See this for more info: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/campaigns